# Sorting Array with JavaScript reduce function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, reduce

Often I  study some `JavaScript` interview questions, suddenly I saw a question about usage of `reduce` function for sorting an `Array`, I read about it in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and the usage of it in some `medium` articles, But sorting an `Array` is so Innovative:

```
const arr = [91,4,6,24,8,7,59,3,13,0,11,98,54,23,52,87,4];
```

I thought a lot, but I've no idea about how answer this question, how must be the `reduce` `call back` function? what is the `initialValue` of `reduce` function? And what are the `accumulator` and `currentValue` of `call back` function of `reduce`?

And at the end, does this way have some benefits than other sorting algorithms? Or Is it useful to improve other algorithms?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It makes no sense to use reduce here, however you could use a new array as an accumulator and do insertion sort with all elements:

```js
array.reduce((sorted, el) => {
  let index = 0;
  while(index < sorted.length && el < sorted[index]) index++;
  sorted.splice(index, 0, el);
  return sorted;
}, []);
```

Here is the version *without* reduce:

```
array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

---

Now some general tips for writing reducers:

> how must be the reduce call back function?

You either take an approach with an accumulator, then the reducer should apply a modification to the accumulator based on the current element and return it:

```js
(acc, el) => acc
```

Or if accumulator and the elements have the sane type and are logically equal, you dont need to distinguish them:

```js
 (a, b) => a + b
```

> what is the initialValue of reduce function?

You should ask yourself *"What should reduce return when it is applied on an empty array?"*

> Now the most important: When to use reduce? (IMO)

If you want to boil down the values of an array into *one single value or object*.

Answer (score 10):

`Array.sort` mutates the array where using `Array.reduce` encourages a pure function. You could clone the array before sorting.

I believe this question is designed to get you thinking differently by enforcing constraints. It tests your knowledge of how `reduce` works and as the answers show there are many ways to skin a cat. It'll show your personal flavour of js in solving this.

I chose to use `Array.findIndex` and `Array.splice`.

```js
const sortingReducer = (accumulator, value) => {
  const nextIndex = accumulator.findIndex(i => value < i );
  const index = nextIndex > -1 ? nextIndex : accumulator.length;
  accumulator.splice(index, 0, value);
  return accumulator;
}

const input = [5,4,9,1];
const output = input.reduce(sortingReducer, []);
```

Testing with the sample input produces

```js
arr.reduce(sortingReducer, [])
// (17) [0, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 8, 11, 13, 23, 24, 52, 54, 59, 87, 91, 98]
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's an (imo) more elegant version of [Jonas W's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50246094/7126740) insertion sort solution. The callback just builds a new array of all lower values, the new one and all higher values. Avoids using explicit loops or indices, so it's easier to see at a glance that it works correctly.

```js
const insertValue = (arr, value) =>
  [...arr.filter(n => n <= value), value, ...arr.filter(n => n > value)]

const testArr = [91, 4, 6, 24, 8, 7, 59, 3, 13, 0, 11, 98, 54, 23, 52, 87, 4]

console.log(testArr.reduce(insertValue, []))
```

Comment: Possible gotcha on this: Any `NaN` entries in the array will be removed, since `NaN` is neither `<= value` or `> value`. Obviously, there's no `NaN` in the OP's example and rather a special case, just pointing it out.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, didn't know that. I'm not going to modify the code, but I guess `n <= value || Number.isNaN(n)` would handle it. Or replace `n <= value` with `!(n > value)` to make sure no special cases could break it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of the `sorting` an array in descending order using reduce function.

> what is the initialValue of reduce function

In this below function the initial value is the `[]` which is passed as `thisArg` in the reduce function.

```
 array.reduce(function(acc,curr,currIndex,array){
        //rest of the code here
        },[]//this is initial value also known as thisArg)
```

So basically an empty array is passed and the elements will be be pushed to this array

The accumulator here is the empty array.

```js
const arr = [91, 4, 6, 24, 8, 7, 59, 3, 13, 0, 11, 98, 54, 23, 52, 87, 4];
var m = arr.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
  // this arrVar will have the initial array
  let arrVar = arr;
  // get the max element from the array using Math.max
  // ... is spread operator
  var getMaxElem = Math.max(...arrVar);
  // in the accumulator we are pushing the max value
  acc.push(getMaxElem);
  // now need to remove the max value from the array, so that next time it 
  // shouldn't not be considered
  // splice will return a new array
  // now the arrVar is a new array and it does not contain the current
  // max value
  arrVar = arrVar.splice(arrVar.indexOf(getMaxElem), 1, '')
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(m)
```

Comment: what changes should be done for asc order? @brk

Comment: @Andres VERY SIMPLE! just do
`m.reverse()`

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` constraints yourself to *online sorting algorithms*, where each element in the array is seen once and you do not now in advance the length of your array (note that using closures you could give more information to the reducing function but this kinds of defeats the purpose of the question).

insertion sort is an obvious and easy example; I won't detail the implementation as the other answers are already very good in this regard. However you can mention a few optimizations that might probably seen as very positive to the interviewer:

- Use binary search to find the insertion point can reduce the complexity of an insertion step from O(n) to O(log n). This is called binary insertion sort: the overall number of comparisons will go from O(n^2) to O(n log n). This won't be faster because the real cost is due to "splicing" the output array but if you had expensive comparisons (say, sorting long strings for instance) it could make a difference.
- If you sort integer, you can use [**radix sort**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) and implement a linear online sorting algorithm with reduce. This is quite trickier to implement, but very suited to a reduction.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some functions for getting an array if not an array is supplied, a function which returns a sorted array by taking two parameters and a sort callback which includes the above by using another reduce method for getting a part result of a sorted array.

```js
const
    getArray = a => Array.isArray(a) ? a : [a],
    order = (a, b) => a < b ? [a, b] : [b, a],
    sort = (a, b) => getArray(a).reduce((r, v) => r.concat(order(r.pop(), v)), [b]),
    array = [91, 4, 6, 24, 8, 7, 59, 3, 13, 0, 11, 98, 54, 23, 52, 87, 4];

console.log(array.reduce(sort));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an insertion sort:

```js
let array        = [91, 4, 6, 24, 8, 7, 59, 3, 13, 0, 11, 98, 54, 23, 52, 87, 4];
let countIfLess  = (array,v)=> array.reduce((c,n)=>n<v?c+1:c,0);
let countIfEqual = (array,v)=> array.reduce((c,n)=>n==v?c+1:c,0);

console.log(
  array.reduce(
    (a,v,i,array)=>( a[countIfLess(array,v) + countIfEqual(a,v)]=v, a ),
    new Array(array.length)
  )
);
```

This will create the destination array once and then perform insertions into it at each step of the reduce without having to recreate the destination array.

There are more efficient ways of implementing `countIfEqual` but I chose to implement all the functions using `reduce` rather than other array functions.

Answer (score 1):

A terrible sorting algorithm can be written in a one liner with ES6:

```
const sorter = (xs, x) => xs.slice(-1)[0] >= x ? [x, ...xs] : [...xs, x];
```

If the present element is larger or equal the last element of the previously sorted list it is appended to the end, otherwise to the beginning.

```
[3,4,1].reduce(sorter,[]).reduce(sorter,[])

//returns [1,3,4]
```

It takes several applications to its return to sort anything but the most simple arrays.

But it will eventually get there. That calls for a recursion!

```js
const arr = [91,4,6,24,8,7,59,3,13,0,11,98,54,23,52,87,4];

const sorter2 =(as) => as.reduce(
  (xs, x) => x >= xs.slice(-1)[0] ? [...xs, x] 
    : xs[0] < x ? sorter2([x, ...xs])
    : [x, ...xs],
  [],
);

const result = sorter2(arr);

console.log(result.join(', '));
```

When the present value is larger than the last value of already processed array it is appended. If it is smaller than the first element it is prepended. Only if it is neither before or after the the present value and the accumulated array are sorted again by a recursive call. The method should be equivalent to an insertion sort (please comment!).

Answer (score 0):

Though, reduce is not ideally meant for the sorting. The following solution is just like a `forEach` or any loop function trying to be achieved with `Array.reduce` function.

```js
var arr = [91,4,6,24,8,7,59,3,13,0,11,98,54,23,52,87,4];

arr = arr.reduce(function(acc,val){
  
  if(acc.length) {
    var temp = [];
    while(acc[acc.length -1] > val) {
      temp.push(acc.pop());
    } 
    acc.push(val);
    while(temp.length) {
      acc.push(temp.pop());
    }
  } else {
    acc.push(val);  
  }
  return acc;
  
}, []);

console.log(arr);
```

Please note, you can use the native function [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for sorting and can also have your own custom sort function where you can define your own sorting algorithm.