# Merge and reduce multidimensional array of number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have searched for similar questions on here but the expected result does not meet my needs. Consider the following multidimensional array.

```
let list = [
   [1,   10,    13,    4],
   [5,   6,    83,    45],
   [9,   18,   11,   12]
];
```

How would you go about merging all values to produce the following result.

```
const output = [15, 34, 107, 61];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce the array by adding up the numbers:

```
 list.reduce((a, b) => a.map((n, i) => n + b[i]))
```

(This will fail if the arrays got different lengths)

Comment: The good news is that it works, could you give a brief explanation so I can understand why it works?

Comment: @jermaine you should read about reduce first, MDN has a good explanation, also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245957/sorting-array-with-javascript-reduce-function/50246094#50246094) might help