# adding items length of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object with some array items, now I have to calculate the length of all items. I got an idea to calculate these items, I declared `count = 0` variable, then calculated these items length & added with `count` variable.

```js
var obj = {
  item_1: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'],
  item_2: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5'],
  item_3: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
}

var count = 0;

Object.entries(obj).map(item => {
  count += item[1].length
})

console.log(count)
```

My question is: how can I get this result without declaring `calculate` variable?   example: `console.log(Object.entries(Obj)....?)`

Comment: What is the `calculate` variable? Do you mean `count`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for reduce:

```
  Object.values(obj).reduce((sum, subarr) => sum + subarr.length, 0)
```

This is one of the rare good usecases for it, there are a lot of [other cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245957/sorting-array-with-javascript-reduce-function/50246094#50246094) were reduce actually complicates the code, so going with global variables is sometimes the better approach.

Comment: `subarr.length` will return the key length, It should be `subarr[1].length`

Comment: @DelowarHosain I think you are confusing `Object.entries()` with `Object.values()`

Comment: Wow, a kindred spirit who thinks most `reduce` uses are confusing!

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
[].concat.apply([], Object.values(obj)).length
```

or using ES6

```
[].concat(...Object.values(obj)).length
```

i am just adding one more step to  [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)