# Fast sorting with JavaScript built-in functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, built-in

Some time ago, I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245957/sorting-array-with-javascript-reduce-function) on **Stack Overflow** about sorting an array with `JavaScript` `reduce` function. And many kind users answer my question and I got some ideas about implementing a sorting algorithm with `reduce` function.

Actually, In my newest project, I have a big array that should be sort as fast as could happen ever. I implement some algorithms but I think I do not use `JavaScript` functions truly. I read some articles in medium and one of them is [this article](https://hackernoon.com/is-it-possible-to-sort-an-array-faster-than-o-n-log-n-time-a053b942c5fe). I don't seek for a high-performance algorithm for sorting. Just like the article said, there is no fast way faster than **nLog(n)**. I seek a real fast implementation in execution.

Is there a `JavaScript` built-in function for this or do you know an awesome sorting implementation for sorting big scale arrays?

Comment: How big is that array? Can you tell the approximate length of the array?

Comment: @AmmarHasan, The arrays sometimes have 100k about 500k items, but they are not alone, many of them should sort at the same time.

Comment: Are you mutating your array or creating a sorted copy?

Comment: @IvanBurnaev, I know both of them, but I don't know which one of them can be faster.

Comment: Each time when you are creating a new copy of array it costs some memory and time to alloc it. So, mutating is faster one for sure.

Comment: Can you add some code example of array item?

Comment: @IvanBurnaev, the arrays have sometimes 500k of elements. it is regular to add them here. do you have other idea to other place an put their link here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181328/discussion-between-ivan-burnaev-and-angelhotxxx).

Comment: Have you tried the built-in [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method?

Comment: WTH are you doing that has multiple arrays of 100000s of items? Sounds like a job for a database to me.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks for your awesome offer, the `sort` function. I don't know about it. thanks a lot

Comment: Dear @Bergi, why didn't you post your suggestion as an answer? I mean using the `sort` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
   const array1 = [1, 30, 4, 21, 100000];
   array1.sort();
   array1.sort(function sortFunction() {...})
```

More info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort