# Sort array by frequency, delete duplicates and display only the top 3 using reduce - Angular

Tags: angular, sorting, reduce

I have this array :

```
            array = [ 
        { id:1,
        name:"mike"},
        { id:6,
        name:"mike"},
        { id:2,
        name:"clay"},
        { id:3,
        name:"mike"},
        { id:4,
        name:"henry"},
        { id:5,
        name:"henry"},
    ]
```

I would like to sort it by frequency of the name and show only the top 2 entries

So at first I would get this array after sorting it and filtering the duplicates with reduce :

```
array2 = [ 
            {name:"mike"},
            {name:"henry"},
            {name:"clay"}
        ]
```

Then I would like to show only the top 2 entries of the array meaning this :

```
array3 = [ 
            {name:"mike"},
            {name:"henry"}
         ]
```

Comment: Well reduce makes sure the values of the array are filtered so it does the job of a sort and filter functions all in one

Comment: Here is an example, I just don't know how to implement it in my case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245957/sorting-array-with-javascript-reduce-function

Answer (score 0):

Given the array:

```
array = [ 
        { id:1,
        name:"mike"},
        { id:6,
        name:"mike"},
        { id:2,
        name:"clay"},
        { id:3,
        name:"mike"},
        { id:4,
        name:"henry"},
        { id:5,
        name:"henry"},
    ]
```

Use the below compare function to sort the object array.

```
function compare( a, b ) {
  if ( a.name < b.name ){
    return -1;
  }
  if ( a.name > b.name ){
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

 var sortedArray = array.sort( compare );
```

Then you can use the spread operator to sort the array.

```
 var distinctArray = [...new Set(sortedArray.map(x => x.name))];
```

Finally use `splice` to take first 2 items.

```
let finalArray = distinctArray.slice(0, 2);
```

Here is a [working example.](https://jsbin.com/rewohihaqu/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: I can do it using a sort function but I am trying to do it with a reduce. Do you know how to do it with reduce ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the sort function to sort? Any particular reason you want to use reduce?

Comment: I am basing myself of this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50245957/sorting-array-with-javascript-reduce-function